# Is it possible to remove a DragView image after the DragEvent has begun?

Tags: java, javafx, drag-and-drop

In JavaFX, an image can be added next to the cursor when dragging an element:

```
    SnapshotParameters snapshotParameters = new SnapshotParameters();
    dragboard.setDragView(someNode.snapshot(snapshotParameters, null));
```

I want to remove this image from the cursor at a specific point after the DragEvent has started, but before the DragEvent finishes.
Initially, I thought to simply set the dragview to null when I wanted to clear the image:

```
private void onDragExited(DragEvent dragEvent) {
        dragEvent.getDragboard().setDragView(null);
}
```

However, as stated in the Javadoc for the setDragView method:

> This method should be called only when starting drag and drop operation in the DRAG_DETECTED handler, 
>        calling it at other times doesn't have any effect.

So calling setDragView(null) when I want to remove the image does not have an effect.

Is there any way to remove the DragView Image from a DragEvent after the event has started?

Comment: If calling `setDragView(null)` does not work then my guess is that JavaFX does not provide a way to do what you want. However, maybe there's a different approach that could work for you; what are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: I want to show an image next to the cursor when dragging a rectangle. Once the rectangle is dragged over a grid node, the image should disappear and a translucent rectangle would appear in the grid instead (to show what it would look like if the rectangle was dropped at this place in the grid). Currently, however, the image besides the cursor and the translucent rectangle are both showing at the same time.

Comment: I wonder if maybe a _full press-drag-release_ gesture would be more appropriate than a _drag-and-drop_ gesture (differences explained [here](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html))? If not, I suppose you could always forgo the drag view functionality of the `Dragboard` and instead use your own [`Popup`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Popup.html); that would give you more control over the image.

Comment: Popup seems to be what I'm looking for, thank you. If you want to add this as an answer, I will accept it. If not, I will post an answer when I can.